# Crystal Reports: New Page Before when details start on following page?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where sometimes the Details of the Group start on the following page. I'm looking for a way to insert a page break before the Group Header if the Details for that group will not appear on the same page. I can't use "Keep Together" as when I do I sometimes get a mostly blank previous page.

Thanks!

Comment: what are those cases? the number of records in details section?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question? Sometimes there is 1 record, sometimes there is 20 records, in the detail section. What I'm trying to avoid is the group header appearing with no details below it before it has to break to the next page.

Comment: post plz two images of your different cases

Comment: I'm still confused, what cases?

Comment: The case you need to add a blank page before the header, and the case you don't in order not to get blank spaces.